# Is there a solution to an incomplete background image

Tags: html, image, css

It maybe a simple task, however, i am facing a difficulty. I am trying to input a background image for a particular panel / block only . There is already a background image for the complete page. And when i input this kind of code -

```
 <div class="block-inner clearfix" 
  style="background:url('https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/devuser/sites/all/
  BackgroundWallpapersforPortal/Images/m8.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;"
```

The image appears like this -

[image: output of code is this]

How can we fix it ? The background image is incomplete. Doesn't cover the entire block.

Comment: `background-size: cover` ? You really need to show a [MCVE] before anyone can offer a solution.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)